# How to validate gridview column cell

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

How do I  validate gridview column cell based on the previous cell value?

E.g If the current cell value is 10, the next cell value must be greater than 10

Comment: I'm so confused about what u asked @@

Comment: actually i have a grid with two column now i want to validate the column cell if i enter first column cell a number i.e 10 ,now for next row same column cell greater 10 number will exit.

Comment: i fail to understand what should i do

Comment: @minu do you mean 'previews' or 'previous'?

Answer (score 1):

you have CellValidated/CellValidating/CellValueChanged events.

the arguments you get from them including row and column number. all you have left to do is to compare to the row above.